# Why use Pydantic with Django?

Tags: django, pydantic

I am looking to implement Pydantic into my Django app (for learning and interview purposes), but I'm wondering why would I? Why should I use data validation on things like Django models when the fields themselves already have types declared on them? Are there any other instances in a Django app where it makes sense to use data validation? Please be kind in your responses. I am genuinely curious and asking honestly.

I have tried researching reasons to use Pydantic in a Django app, but have not found any strong arguments for its use.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

Pydantic does not have any overlapping use case with Django Models. It has overlapping use case with Django Forms.

Django models allows you to do database/model level validation, but models does not do any parsing from serialised data and it doesn't produce error messages in a form that you can use for customers.

Also many of model validations are done through database validations, and checking for database validations requires that you send the query to the database, trigger some constraint errors, and then having to revert the database cursor state through a savepoint/atomic block. That recovery strategy is expensive in the database when the database is the hardest component to scale. And also, the database generally don't really produce any error messages that you can pass on to the user; their error messages usually refer to the internal db field names and the error may just refer to the name of the constraints being validated.

Instead, the common strategy in Django applications is usually to pre validate as much as possible in the application layer, using Django Forms, before sending a query that is mostly should already be valid to the database. That reduces the type of errors the database can produce to things like unique constraint errors that can't really be checked at the application level.

Pydantic doesn't have overlapping functionality with Django Models. Its functionality overlaps more with Django Forms.

Why might you want to use Pydantic in a Django application? Django Form is heavily oriented towards the use case of working with HTML Forms. If your application is serving an API, Pydantic can be less awkward than Django Forms.

Pydantic does parsing, type coercion, validations, and serialisation for arbitrarily nested JSON and dict like objects. Forms does all that too, but only for flat dictionary.

However, a more common option for working with APIs in Django would be Django REST Framework serializers. DRF is much better integrated with the rest of Django.

In practice, if you're using Pydantic in a Django project, it's much more likely you're not using it to replace forms or models, but rather you use it when you need to validate data in other places, like when making JSON API requests to other APIs or non-ORM database, or to parse local files.

Answer (score 0):

**Pydantic is a Python library used to perform data serialization and validation.**
Let us begin with an example. You create a project with the help of the django rest framework. Now you create a register API so that you store some data like(username,firstname,lastname,phone,email) in the database. Now you say I add some required mate in model like(length="",null=True......), but if you do some validation in your serializers.py, that helps to perfect the data stored what you want .

example:

in **models.py**

```
phone  =  models.charfiled(max_length=15)
```

and

in **serializers.py**

```
len(phone) != 10: ---> when you enter phone digit (x)---->>x<10>x in case fetching some error
```

To save time, enter a character such as --989944asdsd

that time they save it but  when you validation add that time perfect enter only digit.

I hope you got it.